Difference between REQUIRE SSL and REQUIRE X509 for MariaDB connections?
I have a vague idea between REQUIRE SSL and REQUIRE X509, I just don't understand how the client and server relationship works in terms of securing the connection.
With REQUIRE SSL, the connection from client to server is secured, but how is this happening if the client has no certificate to show? Is this the equivalent as a web browser going to a website with a self-signed certificate and getting the warning to accept before viewing the site?
And if I'm using REQUIRE X509, how does that help the server verify that the client is one of ours or is that not the case if I just install any certificate? Can X509 be configured so that the server will only accept clients with certificates from the same Certificate Authority as the server?

MariaDB has a detailed article explaining the differences - have you read that first? If not, please do read it first, and then we'll be happy to answer any follow-on questions you have.

@Dai I have and it's still not clear how it's handled which is why I posted this. At least not that I can understand.

"With REQUIRE SSL, the connection from client to server is secured" - That's not my interpretation: the documentation states that REQUIRE SSL is a policy setting, set on a per-USER basis: if that USER attempts to connect without using SSL/TLS then the server won't let them get past the auth stage. I'm not sure where you're getting the "the connection from client to server is secured" bit from...

Whereas REQUIRE X509 is the (badly named) policy that sets a requirement for a client-side certificate. TLS in general, and REQUIRE SSL here, does not require a client-side certificate to ensure that a connection is secure, it just means that the client-side is not preauthenticated using their X.509 with the TLS stream.

"how does that help the server verify that the client is one of ours or is that not the case if I just install any certificate?" - The client's certificate needs to be signed by a CA that's already trusted by the server, which means these CAs are usually internal to an organization and very tightly guard who gets issued certificates and will have revocation systems in-place. So i the client simply uses "any" certificate then MariaDB will reject it by default because it won't be sgined by the specific CA(s) that you've configured Maria to look for and require.

@Dai The link you posted says even though the authentication is only one way with REQUIRE SSL, the connection is encrypted. This was my understanding as well. I'm just trying to relate it to a PC connecting to a website. Is this equivalent to a self-signed cert and getting the SSL warning.

@Dai As for X509, that's what I wanted clarification on is if the Certificate Authority of both client and server had to be the same or if the client just needed to present any certificate using it's own CA. This is how I read it. If that's the case, then the server is still not verifying the client belongs to us, just that it has a certificate.

It sounds like with X509, I would have to add REQUIRE ISSUER

Is this equivalent to a self-signed cert and getting the SSL warning? No, not at all. ...if the Certificate Authority of both client and server had to be the same.... No, it doesn't. The server will send the clients the names of the certificate authorities it trusts, likely what  REQUIRE ISSUER is for. Typically this will include the CA that signed the server's certificate, but there's no requirement for that. ...or if the client just needed to present any certificate using it's own CA... No, the client must present a cert signed by one of the CAs from the list the server sent.

REQUIRE SSL means that the client needs to establish a TLS connection to the server.
REQUIRE X509 means that in addition to a TLS connection the client must also provide a valid X509 certificate/key which will be validated by the server during TLS handshake. It's not possible to configure the server to accept self signed certificates (unless you add the client certificate to a trusted list).
A TLS connection is considered to be secure, if both client and server validated the peer certificates successfully.
